# Отсутствуют методы vue js в поле methods

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет, собственно такая проблема. Есть компонент VueJS 2.0. Находится он в файле .vue. Подключаю в этот файл js с логикой как 
`<script src="/templates/Users/widgets/ProfileWidget/logic.js"></script>`.
сам js

```js
module.exports = {
    data: function () {
        return {
            user: {},
            auth: false,
            ready: false,
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        users_data.setAuth();
        if (users_data.auth) {
            this.user = users_data.auth_user;
            this.auth = users_data.auth;
        }
        this.ready = true;
    },
    methods: {
        logout: function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/users/logout',
                type: "POST",
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                },
            });
        },
        permission: function (permission) {
            console.log(permission);
            return users_data.permission(this.user, permission);
        },
    },
}
```

Но в объекте vue есть все переменные из data, и только первый метод из methods. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В чем может быть проблем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам разобрался. Vue кэширует однофайловые компоненты.